# Why does git rm not work?

Tags: git

I am trying to remove a dir from the remote git repository. However, when I do:

```
$ git rm --cached QTNNSimplePredictTensorflowDataGen_HLD_240_DOI_1_PG_1_WD_0.0_SOT_allpair_20150701_20160630_TE_442_DOR_0.09_AF_sigmoid
    fatal: pathspec 'QTNNSimplePredictTensorflowDataGen_HLD_240_DOI_1_PG_1_WD_0.0_SOT_allpair_20150701_20160630_TE_442_DOR_0.09_AF_sigmoid' did not match any files
```

I get a fatal error. Any idea?

```
$ ls
QTNNSimplePredictTensorflowDataGen_HLD_2000,2000_DOI_2_PG_1_WD_0.0_SOT_allpair_20140101_20151231_TE_443_DOR_0.02_AF_sigmoid
QTNNSimplePredictTensorflowDataGen_HLD_240_DOI_1_PG_1_WD_0.0_SOT_allpair_20140101_20151231_TE_442_DOR_0.09_AF_sigmoid
QTNNSimplePredictTensorflowDataGen_HLD_240_DOI_1_PG_1_WD_0.0_SOT_allpair_20150701_20160630_TE_442_DOR_0.09_AF_sigmoid
```

Comment: You need to use `git rm --cached <file>`  I am voting to close this question as being a typo.

Comment: no, it is not because of the the typo... I corrected it , it still has the same issue

Comment: Are you sure this folder exists?

Comment: yep. it is right there

Comment: Try this: `git rm -r --cached FolderName`

Comment: Today, I experienced the same issue. After running `git rm --cached <file>` the file was still listed with `git status`. Executing `git reset` finally removed the file (and all other files) from the cached file list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused you have removed it in git version control.

You can use `git status` find it. Just delete it directly in your working directory.